# ng-repeat track by $index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I am using `track by $index` to work around duplicate identifiers.  I have an array with 4 undefined values.  I want blank entries to be displayed for the undefined values so that values with the same name are parallel to each other.  I am using Twitter Bootstrap's grid, specifically the `col-*-6` classes to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="cluster in joinedArr track by $index">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{cluster.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
Value 1   Value 1
Value 2   Value 2
Value 3   Value 3
Value 4   Value 5
Undefined Value 6
...
```

**Output I want**

```
Value 1   Value 1
Value 2   Value 2
Value 3   Value 3
Value 4   Undefined
Value 5   Undefined
...
```

The first undefined value is not being picked up for some reason, but it's in the array where it's supposed to be when I use `console.log`.

The controller is using a service that consumes JSON data.  There are two large parent objects.  These objects contain duplicate identifiers; some children that are in the parentA are also in parentB.  In the controller I am assigning children in parentA to an array, and the children in parentB to the array in alternating order.  I didn't know the JSON was organized this way, but I think the children that are in parentA and not in parentB are empty objects in parentB.  So when I assign the empty objects to an array, they are inserted as undefined values.  This actually works out nicely.

Previously, I had this logic in the view, which was really bad.  It had nested `ng-repeats` and an `ng-if` in the repeats... it was bad.  So I think this way is a big improvement.

**Controller**

```
InstanceFctry.query(function(data)
{
    $scope.clusterArr = [];
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 22; i += 2)
    {
        $scope.clusterArr[i] = data.WNG.CUST_CLUSTERS[count + 1];
        $scope.clusterArr[i + 1] = data.KC.CUST_CLUSTERS[count + 1];
        count++;
    }
});
```

However, I am stumped as to why the first undefined value is not being displayed in the view.

**EDIT:**

[Pastebin of the JSON data](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13299543/).

[Array console log snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzyG.jpg).

Comment: I am not in control of creating this JSON data.  I just consume it.  That's not a bad idea, though.  It would make my life a lot easier.  Perhaps I could talk with the person producing it, but right now I'd just like to know a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a pastebin, or gist of the full data structure from a console log. Could you provide one.

Comment: @SeanLarkin Are you talking about the JSON itself or the joined array?

Comment: Both would work great. Provides some better context on why your problem is happening.

Comment: @SeanLarkin I updated the question with both.  In the JSON, the two parents I am talking about are `parent1` and `parent2`.  The original JSON contains sensitive data, so I replaced all the keys and values with dummy data, which is what you're seeing.  The children I am posting are the `clusters`, not `subclusters`.  I am posting the names of the `clusters` in the view.

Comment: In the console.log, are the empty strings your `undefined` values that should be appearing side by side?

Comment: @SeanLarkin Yes.  I was replacing the undefined values with empty strings in the controller (the if statement), but I get the same result when I don't do that.

Comment: What if instead of empty strings you replaced them with empty objects and removed the track by. I can't remember if angular treats empty objects as duplicates or still unique objects.

Comment: @SeanLarkin Well I could try that but I think I'd still have to use `track by` since the other cluster pairs have the same name.

Comment: I get the same result.  I'll try a different way of handling this in the controller I guess.